# How do I inject service dependencies into MVC sitemap DynamicNodeProviderBase using StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, structuremap, mvcsitemapprovider

Consider the following code:

```
    public class InboxMenuItemDynamicProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
    {
      private IMyService _myService { get; set; }

      public InboxMenuItemDynamicProvider(IActionService actionService)
      {
         _myService = myService;
      }

      public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
      { 
        // use _myService here....e.g. db access 
      }
    }
}
```

How do I go about injecting a service dependency into a  Mvc Sitemap DynamicNodeProvider using StructureMap and MVC3?  I'm using the MVC3 dependency resolver.

However, on running the app, I get a 'no default constructor' error.  I need to somehow inject service dependencies into the provider, but I'm at a total loss as to where/how I can inject them. I don't even know if its possible as Mvc Site Map might be outside of the depency resolver.

Comment: can you show the registry code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this link:
http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/discussions/263971

I think you could just use:

```
private IMyService _myService 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyService>(); 
    } 
}
```

and do nothing specific in your constructor

Comment: OK, so rather than use dependency injection, just resolve it at runtime? I suppose I don't need to unit test it so DI is not really required.

Comment: Everything is resolved at runtime using DI. You could still unit test this, you just have to configure your container differently.